# Segate hard drive PC to Mac

Tags: mac

I have a Seagate 250GB external hard drive that I bought for a PC and it works well. Wanting to switch to a Mac, I put all my data on it but I can't transfer any files over to the Mac now. The Mac sees the Seagate but I can't move files. When I "Get info" on the drive it says "Read Only." I was told MacFUSE 2.0 would do the trick, but no luck so far. I would appreciate a solution if one is known. Thank you! Ken

Comment: Based on the MacFUSE reference, I'm assuming the file system is NTFS. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the NTFS-3G NTFS Read/Write driver for Mac you need MacFUSE and NTFS-3G for it to work. (Check out paragraph 1, page 3: http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/ntfs-3g/macntfs-3g_userguide.pdf)

Download: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/
Manual: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/

Comment: Standard disclaimer applies: NTFS-3G is a reverse-engineered interpretation of NTFS by Microsoft, so some problems may arise. It is for this reason that FAT32 partitions are recommended when sharing between MacOS and Windows. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Randolph True, however almost all NTFS projects are... NTFS is closed to unlicensed devlopers.

Comment: actually it is fairly well described in various publications, including "Inside the Windows NT File system" by Helen Custer, who is one of its principal architects.

Comment: @psusi although described, the original specifications are not open to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a silly question, but are you trying to *move* the files (i.e., "cut"), or *copy* them?  The cut operation would attempt to remove the files from the external drive, which won't be possible because it's read-only.  But a copy operation may work because it's not attempting to erase anything off the read-only external drive.